# Included Resource files in published site

Tags: asp.net, web-deployment

How to include resource files while publishing ASP.NET site ? In normal, it is not included.

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution. Need to convert my site to Web Application. For the Resource files I want to published, performed following actions:

Set the "Build Action" to Content.
Set the "Copy to Output Directory" to Copy always.